# R tibble rename columns with regular expressions

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse

I have multiple duplicated columns in a table after several dplyr::joins. A simple version of the table looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4.x col4.y col5.x col5.y
```

I want to get to rename to:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
```

I was able to remove the *.y columns with `select(tablename, -matches("*.y"))`

Resulting in:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4.x col5.x
```

From here, I am thinking the `rename_if()` should work, but I am at a loss as to how to get col4.x and col5.x renamed to col4 and col5.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `setNames(tablename, gsub("\\.x$", "", names(tablename)))`

Comment: you should also review the `by` parameter in your `join` functions. This is the reason you are getting .x and .y. Or, you can do `select(-col5)` on one of the two data frames you are joining to eliminate the duplicate to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mytibble %>% rename_all(gsub, pattern = '\\.x', replacement = '')`

Comment: This has been superseded by `rename_with()`.